# mpi_run on multicore architecture --bind-to l3 or --bind-to core

Tags: multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, mpi, multicore

I am running a code on a 24c architecture and would like to use one mpi rank for each set of three cores bound to a L3 cache bloc. So, 8 mpi ranks per socket, 16 per node, with 3 threads per rank. I think the following command line should apply

```
mpirun --bind-to l3 -np 16 gmx_mpi mdrun -nt 3
```

`--bind-to` binding the mpi ranks to each bloc of L3 cache, `-np` allocating 16 mpi ranks per node and a `-nt` a number of threads per MPI rank of 3. Is this the correct approach ?

If the core is capable of multithreading (2 threads) is it right to write

```
mpirun --bind-to l3 -np 16 gmx_mpi mdrun -nt 6
```

`--bind-to core` is I assume binding one MPI rank per core, with no spanning into threads, or spanning into 2 threads per core for exploiting MT, e.g.

```
mpirun --bind-to core -np 48 gmx_mpi mdrun -nt 2
```

with 48 ranks one per core on a 2-socket platform and 2 threads per core (MT)

Would you confirm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exact command seems to be `--bind-to l3cache`

```
mpirun --bind-to l3cache -np 16 gmx_mpi mdrun -nt 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use this piece of code, that I inherited from somewhere many years ago, to print out bindings at runtime. For example, on my 4-core laptop:

```
dsh@e7390dh:binding$ mpicc -o bind bind.c utilities.c
dsh@e7390dh:binding$ mpirun -n 4 ./bind
Rank 2 on core 2,6 of node <e7390dh>
Rank 3 on core 3,7 of node <e7390dh>
Rank 0 on core 0,4 of node <e7390dh>
Rank 1 on core 1,5 of node <e7390dh>
```

i.e. each process is bound to one physical core but can run on either hypercore. If there is no binding you get a range, e.g. "on core [0-7]".

Hope this is useful.

bind.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void printlocation();

int main(void)
{
  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
  printlocation();
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

utilities.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sched.h>

#include <mpi.h>

/* Borrowed from util-linux-2.13-pre7/schedutils/taskset.c */
static char *cpuset_to_cstr(cpu_set_t *mask, char *str)
{
    char *ptr = str;
    int i, j, entry_made = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++) {
    if (CPU_ISSET(i, mask)) {
        int run = 0;
        entry_made = 1;
    for (j = i + 1; j < CPU_SETSIZE; j++) {
        if (CPU_ISSET(j, mask)) run++;
        else break;
        }
        if (!run)
        sprintf(ptr, "%d,", i);
        else if (run == 1) {
        sprintf(ptr, "%d,%d,", i, i + 1);
        i++;
        } else {
        sprintf(ptr, "%d-%d,", i, i + run);
        i += run;
        }
        while (*ptr != 0) ptr++;
    }
    }
    ptr -= entry_made;
    *ptr = 0;
    return(str);
}

void printlocation()
{
    int rank, namelen;
    char hnbuf[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);    
    memset(hnbuf, 0, sizeof(hnbuf));
    MPI_Get_processor_name(hnbuf, &namelen);

    cpu_set_t coremask;
    char clbuf[7 * CPU_SETSIZE];
    memset(clbuf, 0, sizeof(clbuf));
    (void)sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(coremask), &coremask);
    cpuset_to_cstr(&coremask, clbuf);
    printf("Rank %d on core %s of node <%s>\n", rank, clbuf, hnbuf);
}
```